# Calling methods written in class library project from webforms in ASP.net using LINQ to entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, webforms

I have a class library project where i have written my methods that retrieve data from database using entity framework. But I don't know how to call that methods from my UI webforms backend. Please Help.

Comment: Is your class library in `dll` type ? And is the method written in your library in public ?

Comment: yes they are public...i dont know type of class library...may b it is dll type

Comment: it is allready added and i have changed the namespace according to that dll reference name..but in the code behind of webform the methods are not accessible yet.....can you please give some code example

Comment: Check my answer Raza. if my answer doesn't solve your problem , can you show some code of your method in classLibrary ?

Comment: public static IList<Lab> GetAllLabs()
        {
            var context = new CRMEntities();
            return context.Labs.ToList();
        }    this is the method to whom i want to call in another project that is a web project.....i am stuck

Comment: can you please explain your this line" Declare this reference as namespace and you can call your method." do you mean i should code like "using system.referencename" ? or change existing namespace ->(namespace referencename)

Answer (score 0):

Build your class library and find the dll in bin folder . And add this dll as reference in another Project which you want to use it in . Declare this reference as namespace and you can call your method.

You can reference this [Creating C# Class Library (DLL)](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/9c667330-0966-4e38-a689-61fed9cbbb4c/Creating%20C#.VQbfbI6G9hE) link , this example show how to create dll and reference this from console application.

But you can use this example in your `Asp.net` webfrom in the same way .
Hope it's helpful for you :)

Comment: Note: If you're trying to go to the revision history of this answer and it crashes your browser, see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=467534.